# Cannot delete SharePoint Web Application

Tags: 2010

Attempting to delete the 'SharePoint - 80' Web Application, but seem to get an error:

> The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

When checking the log file, I get:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.      at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_IsContainer()     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.ChildEnumerator..ctor(DirectoryEntry container)     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntries.GetEnumerator()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebSite.LookupByServerComment(String serverComment, Int32& instanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProvisioningAssistant.UnprovisionWebApplication(Boolean deleteWebSites, String[] serverComments)     at Microsoft.Shar...    92470f38-ed8e-4e6c-8039-d2fe4865cbae
>
> ...ePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.UnprovisionIisWebSitesAsAdministrator(Boolean deleteWebSites, String[] serverComments, String applicationPoolId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.Unprovision(Boolean deleteWebSites)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication.UnprovisionGlobally(Boolean deleteIisWebSite)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.DeleteWebApplicationPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Bo... 92470f38-ed8e-4e6c-8039-d2fe4865cbae
>
> ...olean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 92470f38-ed8e-4e6c-8039-d2fe4865cbae

What 'service' is it trying to run, all the ones named 'SharePoint' in Services are running? How can I delete the application?

Comment: Have you tried an iisreset then re-attempting this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching for the error I stumbled upon this [post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aXw8Yq5PVgpcJ%3awww.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21403824.html+System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind&cd=3&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl) on EE.
From which I assume it's probably a network or security related error. 
Also, [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329986) post on Microsoft might help a bit. 
Could it be that the account of the application pool has changed? If so, Sharepoint might nog have enough permissions to do stuff in the application pool, like deleting websites and folders.
I don't know exactly what the Bind() does, but it's probably some directory binding method. Are you sure the website still exists in IIS and on the file system? If one of those directories is deleted manually, you could receive such an error I guess.

If you run in a farm, check out all servers to see of permissions are in order and the websites still exist on the whole farm.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try this:
restart your SharePoint server and then try to delete web application.
Also check SQl server whether database for web application exist or not.

Comment: After deleting a web application it did not complete the delete until after a server restart. Until the server was restarted it looked like the web application still existed.